# Error: Unsupported desugared library configuration version, please upgrade the D8/R8 compiler

Tags: android

I keep my dependencies up to date. Then I try to push `desugar_jdk_libs` up to anything from `1.0.9` ,I get this error. Here are my dependencies:

`app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.6.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.5.0"
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.2.0'
}
```

I get this error :

```
Error: Unsupported desugared library configuration version, please upgrade the D8/R8 compiler
```

Why?